# Predict future values using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am pretty new to creating neural networks, and I am trying to use Keras in python to create a model that will predict a sequence based on the first ~100 inputs.

I am using 11x10000 arrays to predict a single output value, and I have created a NN that will fit that regression pretty well. However, I want to create another NN that will predict the inputs for the regression NN.

I have a very large dataset at my disposal for training, and I am trying to predict a 11x10000 array using the first few inputs of an array.

I can get it to predict the expected value at the current time step, but I want it to predict far future values based on current and near future values.

Here is some code:

```py
names = getNames()
test = getNames()

for index in range(len(names)):
        print(index)
        X, Y = getData(names, index, False)
        X_test, Y_test = getData(test, index, True)

        NN = makeNN(X,Y, X_test, X_test)
```

```py
def getModel():
    keras.backend.clear_session()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=11, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(11, init='uniform', activation='relu'))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

    return model
```

```py
def makeNN(X, Y, X_test, Y_test):
    try:
        model = keras.models.load_model('./trajSweepNNVacc.h5')
        print("previous model loaded")
    except:
        model = getModel()
        print("new model created")


    X_train = X[0:]

    print('Training -----------')

    model.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=2)

    print('\nTesting ------------')
    cost = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
    print('test cost:', cost)
    W, b = model.layers[0].get_weights()


    model.save('trajSweepNNVacc.h5')
    return model
```

I want to get it to predict the future 10000 values, but currently I can only have it predict a current value

Comment: What is your model?

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B just added the getModel() function. The model that I am loading is one trained off of the same architecture

Comment: To predict future values based on current values, you to use RNNs, like sequence to sequence models.

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B that looks like something that will help greatly, thanks